# Prevent ionRangeSlider to change the value after mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ion-range-slider

In this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/qv6yrjrv/), hold down the mouse key and drag outside of the JSFiddle result iframe.

Then release the button. Move the mouse over the slider. Then, the slider value will be changed, without holding down the button.

How to prevent this behavior?

The code is pretty simple:

```
var $range = $(".js-range-slider");

$range.ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    min: 100,
    max: 1000,
    from: 300,
    to: 800
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, assign ionRangeSlider to one variable, read [docs](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html)

```
var slider = $(".js-range-slider").data("ionRangeSlider");
```

so, the slider object has the property `dragging: true`

once, you can mouseout from the main container, make `dragging: false`

```
var slider = $(".js-range-slider").data("ionRangeSlider");

$(".range-slider").mouseleave(function(){
  slider.dragging = false;
});
```

check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nageshwar521/xugp3gjd/)